# Validating DTOs with ModelState

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating .NET Core WEB API project together with Entity Framework using Code First approach. I have troubles validating input from the requests, as
ModelState validation is always true.

My application consists of 3 layers.

- Data Access Layer
- Business Logic Layer
- .NET Core API

Example DataModel in DAL:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long GroupId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Corresponding DTO:

```
public class GroupDto
{
    public long GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] GroupDto groupDto)
{
    Group group = _mapper.Map<Group>(groupDto);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _groupService.Add(group);

    groupDto = _mapper.Map<GroupDto>(group);

     return Ok(groupDto);
}
```

As far as I understand in current state ModelState.IsValid would always return true as GroupDto does not have any validations done via DataAnnotations.

How the DTOs should be validated? I'd like to avoid repeating the same validations in two places. Should additional custom DtoValidator be created or am I missing somtething and there is way to perform those validations.

Comment: You'll need to repeat the rules. The DTO will not necessarily have identical rules as the database. Consider if your application transforms user input into an internal db-only value. Consider if your DTO does not have a 1:1 mapping to the underlying entity fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Model state validation will occur on the model being passed in, which in your case is GroupDto.  Just because you eventually map to the Group class has no bearing on how the validation works.  You will need to repeat the validation attributes in the DTO.  This does duplicate code, but also allows you to customize the rules, since you may or may not want the exact same set in the DTO.  An example of this is your primary key.  For creation (POST) you don't necessarily want the GroupId to be a required field to pass in to the controller since the DB may be auto-generating that field (depending on your setup).

If you are using ASP.Net Core 2.1 or later, you can also now apply the [ApiController] attribute to the controller class and it will automatically apply the model validation rules.  This eliminated the need to manually check for ModelState.IsValid.  The system will automatically return a 400 Bad Request if the model is invalid. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#annotation-with-apicontroller-attribute)

Comment: I was totally not aware of that functionality of [ApiController], thanks for that! From what you've mentioned I understand that I should add respective data annotations to my DTO classes and that would be the first step of the validation.

But how and where shoud the validation of DataModel happen? 
Potentially it could happen in the BLL/Services as they recieve those kind of objects, is my understanding correct? If it is this way, should I create validation methods for those objects or is there anyting similar to ModelState.IsValid construction which I could execute on those objects?

Comment: If you don't use the 2.1 Api Controller path, then simply use the !ModelState.IsValid check in the controller as you have in your example above.  You can move the Map call below the ModelState check, since you don't need to do the Map unless the ModelState is valid.  If you have the validation attributes on your Dto, the checking if the ModelState IsValid is all there is to do.  No need to do it lower down in the BLL.  If you need to have the flexibility of doing validation at numerous layers of your app, it's often easier to externalize it using a separate library, like FluentValidation.

Comment: I add [Required] to the DTO but it does not work. Do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

DTOs and models are different things, so the DataAnnotation attribute should be made in both of them.  The subject checked by "ModelState.IsValid" is the input of the function you work on. Thus, in your code the Model being checked is the GroupDto.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] GroupDto groupDto)
{
    Group group = _mapper.Map<Group>(groupDto);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) // this line will check the validation inside GroupDto
```

Anyway, to make "model validation" clean in the controller I would suggest to use custom ValidateModelAttribute, like this.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace MyWeb.App.Filter
{
  public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuting( HttpActionContext actionContext )
    {
      if( !actionContext.ModelState.IsValid )
      {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
          HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState ); 
        // Path to the error in request content will be sent to the client, so helpful!
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can write the validation on controller like this.

```
[Route( "" )]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateModel] // here you attach the ValidateModelAttribute
[ResponseType( typeof( GroupDto ) )] // Make sure the model is written in Swagger UI
public IHttpActionResult Create( InputDto inputDto )
{
  _groupService.Add(group);

  groupDto = _mapper.Map<GroupDto>(group);

  return Ok(groupDto);
}
```

Hope this answers the question.